# Aptana Ruble - How to switch to another locale?

Tags: ruby, jruby, aptana

According to latest update on Aptana there is an option to externalize UI string for all rubles. 
But the question is how to switch between different locales ? 
is there a bundle parameter called "locale" or... ?

https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10216&version=11505

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Localizing+a+Ruble

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

That option is just the architecture so that Rubles can be localized down the road. If you'd like to contribute international versions of Rubles, please let Appcelerator know.